# How can I fix the bug to realize reference resolution using a library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

## what I would like to do

I would like to replace pronouns to nouns like below using Python 3.6 and spaCy neuralcoref.

```
#input
'My sister has a dog. She loves him.'
'Angela lives in Boston. She is quite happy in that city.'

#output
'My sister has a dog. My sister loves a dog.'
'Angela lives in Boston. Angela is quite happy in Boston.'
```

## error

How can I fix the bug to acquire appropriate output?
If you have any ideas, please share them with me.

```
AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

## current code

The sample code of the use of `neuralcoref` is the following URL:https://spacy.io/universe/project/neuralcoref

```
import spacy
import neuralcoref

nlp = spacy.load('en')
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)
doc1 = nlp('My sister has a dog. She loves him.')
print(doc1._.coref_clusters)
print(doc1._.coref_clusters[0][1])
print(len(doc1._.coref_clusters))
for i in range(1, len(doc1._.coref_clusters)+1):
  doc_new = doc1.replace(doc1._.coref_clusters[0][i], doc1._.coref_clusters[1][i])

print(doc_new)

#output
[My sister: [My sister, She], a dog: [a dog, him]]
She
2
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: first see `print(doc1)` and `print(type(doc1))` - as for me it is not normal `string` which has function `replace()`. Maybe you should assign text to variable `text = 'My sister has a dog. She loves him.'` and then you could use `text.replace()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`neuralcoref` has a specially dedicated [`doc._.coref_resolved`](https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref) method for tasks like this:

```
import spacy
import neuralcoref

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
neuralcoref.add_to_pipe(nlp)
texts = ['My sister has a dog. She loves him.','Angela lives in Boston. She is quite happy in that city.']

docs = nlp.pipe(texts)
inp = []
out = []
for doc in docs:
    inp.append(doc.text)
    out.append(doc._.coref_resolved)

# desired output
print("Input:",inp)
print("Output:", out)
Input: ['My sister has a dog. She loves him.', 'Angela lives in Boston. She is quite happy in that city.']
Output: ['My sister has a dog. My sister loves a dog.', 'Angela lives in Boston. Angela is quite happy in Boston.']
```